# How to solve this differetial equation? $1+(\frac xy -\sin(y))y'= 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$1+(\frac xy - \sin(y))y' = 0$.

I tried use $y = vx$ substitution, but things got worse,
and I have no idea what to do

Comment: Taking $x$ for the dependent variable, the equation can be written $$x'y+x=(xy)'=y\sin(y).$$
So
$$xy=\sin(y)-y\cos(y)+c.$$

Comment: @YvesDaoust. The old good trick ! Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I prefer that solution over that by Nasser. :-)

Comment: @YvesDaoust. Me too. This is the way I would have taken if I had a chance to see the post on time.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: l'avenir appartient à ceux qui se lèvent tôt. [Lao Tseu]

Comment: @YvesDaoust. I start working every single day between 2:00 am and 4:00 am. What about you, early bird ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: when I wake up, it is just past midnight in Denver.

Comment: @YvesDaoust. Why are you awaking in Denver then ?

Comment: Well, I am not. but the Denverite are.